# Why isn't my While True loop breaking?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple chat room, but starting with basics. I have a server sending strings to the client, however, my while loop won't break.

Server

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 50023  # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)
conn.send("hello client")
conn.send("\nhow are you")
conn.send("stop")
```

Client

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50023       # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == "stop": 
        break
    print(data)
print("we got here")
```

Would like to point out I have also tried along the lines of

```
if not data:
   break
```

That didn't work

Comment: My first guess is that `s.recv` returns a *binary* string, and `b'abc' != 'abc'`.

Comment: Also, client expects `data == stop1` and your server sends `stop`

Comment: ah meant to have stop and not stop1, its right in code, wrong in here

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah that may be it. How do i check for a binary string. Would I check data == b'stop' ?

Answer (score 5):

Your server is sending:

```
hello client\nhow are youstop
```

But your client is testing for

```
 stop
```

Since `"hello client\nhow are youstop" != "stop"`, you are unlikely to hit your `break` statement.

Realize that TCP provides a reliable byte stream; as long each individual byte gets to its destination in the correct order, then TCP's job is done. There are no message boundaries, only byte boundaries. One side's `.recv()` need not align in any way whatsoever with the other sides `.send()`.

If you want a service that preserves message boundaries, you might try UDP. Or you can implement your own message framing on top of TCP (newlines, for example, or type-length-value tuples).

Comment: do you mean my server is sending that string, and client is testing for stop. Also how would I be able to separate that string for the rest of the strings sent?

Comment: Sorry, had the roles reversed. Better?

Comment: I thought that a if not data: break would work, however would that give the same problem?

Comment: Ah, Thanks for the information. Did not understand that at first! So I assume I must approach this problem a different way.

Comment: `if not data` can work. When the connection is closed, an empty string `''` is returned from `.recv()`. As long as your server remembers to close the connection, `if not data:` will work in the client.

Comment: "*a different way*" - One way that works well for text-command-oriented protocols is to use `\n` as a frame marker. Every command must exist on its own line. (HTTP, FTP, SMTP each define this sort of protocol.)
 [`socket.makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) is a handy function to use for those sorts of protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Little changes in your code make possible you go ahead in your simple chat.

First of all, don't send strings. Use binary to send messages between your server and the client.

For instance, the code for the server will be:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning the local host
PORT = 50023  # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)
conn.send(b"hello client")
conn.send(b"\nhow are you")
conn.send(b"stop")
```

Note server now is sending binary (use b before string for set binary data).

In the client side, all data that you sent is received like a data stream. To break the while loop you need to check the end of the stream as you can see in the code below:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50023       # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data.endswith(b'stop'): 
        break
    print(data)
print(b"we got here")
```

I hope it could be useful to you!

Comment: To prevent the client from closing the connection before the server sends all the binary strings, is there a better method rather than time.sleep() before "stop" ?